# IIFEs and naming conventions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iife

Maybe I've missed something specific to angular or javascript that requires this but could someone explain if there's a techical reason CarWashService is defined twice below?

```
(function() {

angular.module("cw.services")
    .factory("CarWashService", ['$sce', '$rootScope', function ($sce, $rootScope) {

        var CarWashService;

        return new (CarWashService = (function () {
            function CarWashService() {
                this.results = [];
                this.resultsCountText = "";
                this.PageIndex = 0;
                this.processing = false;
                this.initialized = false;
                this.showNoResults = false;
                this.showResults = false;
                this.noCarWashMessage = $sce.trustAsHtml($rootScope.resources.landingNoCarWashMessage);
            }

            return CarWashService;

        })());

    }]);

}).call(this);
```

What could be throwing me off is calling `return new` on the same line as CarWashService is being assigned.  For the javascript gurus out there would it make sense to use a different name other than CarWashService in the IIFE, for readability if nothing else?  Or is this an accepted pattern when doing IIFEs?

Comment: This just looks overly complicated, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever wrote that just made it needlessly complex, there is absolutely no benefit from just declaring `CarWashService` because they aren't making use of the additional closure that they've created.  Even if they did need a closure for private state, they have the one from the outer function.

As a side note, this also looks incorrect for angular.  If you really wanted a factory, this should probably be returning the constructor rather than an instance of it.  This looks like it should be declared as a service.